# Interval between wav file play loop in c#

Tags: c#

I have 4 seconds wav file. I can play it in loop

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
player.Stream = Properties.Resources.ringtone;
player.PlayLooping();
```

But I have need 2 second interval before playing the wav again.

I mean `4 seconds(sound) + 2 seconds(no sound) + 4 seconds(sound) and so on...`

How it posible.

Comment: Don't use [PlayLooping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.playlooping(v=vs.110).aspx), but some synchronized version (PlaySync?) and put your delays (as `Thread.Sleep`) between plays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a bunch of work doing threads and working with thread pool, it became clear to me that if you have a long running thread you should avoid "stealing" a thread from the thread pool. Thread pool in .NET(and most recently .NET Core) is used mostly for fast asynchronous work where there could be a lot of multi threaded work. They're designed specifically for that, and stealing one could lead to all kinds of problems, especially since some other important work could not have a free thread from thread pool to do it's thing, and frankly you should avoid it.

Whenever you need a long running operation(the lifetime of the app for example) it's just better to spawn a new thread manually and work with that. Just don't forget to mark it as a background thread, and you'll be just fine.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
player.Stream = Properties.Resources.ringtone;

private void LoopSong()
{
     while(true)
     {
         player.Play();
         Thread.Sleep(2000);
     }
}

var thread = new Thread(LoopSong) 
{
    IsBackground = true
};
thread.Start();
```

**BAD CODE BELOW, DON'T USE IT**

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
player.Stream = Properties.Resources.ringtone;

Task.Run(()=>
{
     while (true)
     {
        player.Play();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
     }
});
```

You need to put in the background thread if you don't want to block the gui.

Comment: Its working just need to change `Thread.Sleep(2000);` to  `Thread.Sleep(6000);` (4+2 seconds for complete task). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Threading;

System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
player.Stream = Properties.Resources.ringtone;

while (condition)
{
    player.Play();
    Thread.Sleep(6000);
}
```

You can swap `condition` with `true` for an infinite loop if you want it to play indefinitely, or some other condition depending on your requirement. If this is on the main thread however you will need to create something like a backgroundworker so it doesn't lock up your form.

Answer (score 0):

Player.Play() does not work well if you call it twice or more.
Use this method: player.PlaySync().

```
player.PlaySync();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
player.PlaySync();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
...
```